# How to add zoom-in zoom-out control to an SVG file

Tags: svg, jquery-svg

I'm trying out to bring zoom-in and zoom-out control panel to a .svg file. Basically i'm using the .svg file found in http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4d/US_weather_service_county_map.svg. I can bring custom style and feature to the map. But how can i bring or alter the svg file to have a zoom-in zoom-out control in it (like the one in google maps and all)

Your help will appreciated greatly

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example](https://jwatt.org/svg/tests/zoom-and-pan-controlsViewBox.svg) that shows an SVG file with a zoom/pan control. It sets the currentScale and currentTranslate attributes on the SVG root element to perform zooming/panning.